# Kendo Mobile - Bind to ScrollView's "change" and "changing" events

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Normally, this is a trivial task, but I cannot figure out how to bind to the `"change"` and `"changing"` events of the `ScrollView` widget. I need to bind after declarative initialization of the widget. I am attempting to do this in my view's `init` function

Here's what I've tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="scrollview-container" data-role="scrollview">...</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
initView(e) {
    ...
    $("#scrollview-container").data("kendoMobileScrollView").bind("change", function(e) { console.log("change event"); });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Kendo UI v.2013.1.319 and JQuery 1.9.1

**Update:**

After further testing, I can bind to the change event, but only for swiping pages. Programmatically changing the page does not trigger the change event. No big deal i can work around that.

For some reason, I cannot bind to the `changing` event at all. Mysterious to me...

Comment: Seems ok to me.
Are you sure that you get back the scrollView object when you run this

 `$("#scrollview-container").data("kendoMobileScrollView")`
Try a debugger to be sure on what you get there.

Comment: @Antonis, thanks for the comment. I have run that line through the debugger and I do get the ScrollView object back. Please see my OP, I have updated it.. I only face one issue now where I cannot bind to the "changing" event

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Kendo UI version I am currently using. As a test, I downloaded the Q2 2013 beta release, ran the same code as shown in my original post, and both events were triggered, as expected.